# jsoup not working on android

Tags: android, jsoup

I have a problem with jsoup on android. I have seen the other posts and tried solutions that were suggested there ( re-adding  the jars, calling android fix tool, etc.)

I have added the jsoup jar to my android project (using build path), and added the required 
internet permission to my manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

but when I am trying to run my application I am getting
Could not find method org.jsoup.Jsoup.connect, referenced from method com.example.test.MainActivity.onCreate

I have tried to use the android fix tool but it did not solve the problem.
All I have is a main activity and I am trying to call

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/").get();
```

attached is part of my code
    import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
    import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/").get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Did you check your Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export to make sure Android Private Libraries is checked? And make sure everything else seems legit in there?

Comment: Yep the Jsoup-1.7.2.jar is checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to run your connection in your main thread. Use `AsyncTask` and it will work.

---

I.E.

```
public class JsoupParser extends AsyncTask...
```

---

Why you have to use `AsyncTask` for network connections in android?

AsyncTask is an abstract helper class that enables you to use the UI thread correctly, while performing background operations in a different thread, without having to really handle threads or controllers. Since android is implemented using a single thread model, each time you launch an application, a new thread will be created.

Imagine you have a single thread model where you at a button click will parse a website using `Jsoup`. This would have worked fine in earler android versions, though you would have had a non-responsive screen until the network operation is done. The `AsyncTask` will run in the background enabling your screen to still be responsive while another thread takes care of the network communication.

Take a look in the API:
[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)
[NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html)

Answer (score 1):

In you normal activity
use this

`public static int SDK_INT = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;`

and before fetching Document
write this inside try block

```
if (SDK_INT >= 10) {
    ThreadPolicy tp = ThreadPolicy.LAX;
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(tp);
}
```

it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Delete all statements like:

```
System.out.println(something);
```

It worked for me, realizing this took me 2 hours.